# How to bind custome pipe with reactive form input box Angular 4

Tags: angular, reactive

How to bind custom pipe with reactive form input box Angular 4.

Please check the working code.

```html
<input [ngModel]="datevalue | datePipe"
       (ngModelChange)="datevalue=$event"
       name="dateField"
       type="text" />
```

But I want to bind With

```html
<input type="text" name="dt" formControlName="dt">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use this kind of input in many places, you can create a control which implements **[ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)** and encapsulates this kind of work under the hood. And in other places you can just use

```html
<my-control type="text" name = "dt" formControlName="dt"></my-control>
```

which under it will contain something like

```html
<input [ngModel]="datevalue | datePipe"
       (ngModelChange)="datevalue=$event"
       name="dateField"
       type="text" />
```